# Injecting play.Environment into Jackson serializer using Guice

Tags: java, playframework, jackson, guice

Jackson 2.10.1,
Guice 4.2.2,
Play 2.7.2

I'm trying to inject the play.Environment object into a custom Jackson serializer like so:

```
@Singleton
public class PathSerializer extends StdSerializer<Path> {

  @Inject
  Environment environment;

  public PathSerializer() {
    this(null);
  }

  public PathSerializer(Class<Path> t) {
    super(t);
  }

  @Override
  public void serialize(Path value, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
    Path path = environment.rootPath().toPath().relativize(value.toAbsolutePath());
    generator.writeString(path.toString());
  }
}
```

However, when this serializer is called, a `NullPointerException` is thrown since `environment` is `null`.

This custom serializer is invoked by using the `@JsonSerialize(using = PathSerializer.class)` annotation. From my understanding, when this serializer is initialised, it is managed by Jackson and not Guice, thus the environment cannot be injected, since `PathSerializer` is not a Guice managed bean.

Using Spring, it seems you can use the `@Configurable` annotation as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27369842/inject-service-into-custom-jackson-serializer). But there doesn't seem to be a Play equivalent.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I decided on getting rid of the play.Environment and getting the base path with `String base = new File(".").getCanonicalPath();` which is much more straight forward.
Then I relativised it with `String relative = new File(base).toURI().relativize(new File(value.toString()).toURI()).getPath();`